# Find post where key has specific value in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I need to be able to compare a value in each of the markdown files in a folder called `in_media` to the `user_id` of the current page stored in a `_users` folder and only display the post title that have that value from the `in_media` folder.

**User markdown file in `_users` folder**

```
---
user_id: 123
title: bob
---
```

**Post markdown from `in_media` folder**

```
---
users: 123
---
```

I tried the following:

```
{% for this_user in site.in_media %}
  {% for user in page.user %}
      {% if this_user == user.user_id %}
          <li><a href="{{ post.external_link }}">{{ post.title }}</a </li>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, this is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
{% for post in site.in_media %}
  {% if post.value == page.title %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.external_link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure that you can use `external_link`, never heard of it. Maybe you'll need to build permalink manually - depending on your `_config.xml`.
Also note the collection should be properly [set up](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#permalinks) to work with permalinks.